# What is the difference Array<string> and string[]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Whats is the difference between `Array<string>` and `string[]`?

```
var jobs: Array<string> = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Google'];
var jobs: string[]      = ['Apple', 'Dell', 'HP'];
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

There's no difference between the two, it's the same.

It says this in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array):

> Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use
>   the type of the elements followed by [] to denote an array of that
>   element type:

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

> The second way uses a generic array type, Array:

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

You do need to use the `Array<T>` form when you want to extend it for example:

```
class MyArray extends Array<string> { ... }
```

but you can't use the other form for this.

Comment: I appreciate the mention of "extends".