# How do I check whether an array contains a string in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Currently I am using Angular 2.0. I have an array as follows:

```
var channelArray: Array<string> = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

How can I check in TypeScript whether the channelArray contains a string 'three'?

Comment: It should be `channelArray: string[]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: This isn't Typescript-specific

Comment: @NitzanTomer aren't they the same ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239579/what-is-the-difference-arraystring-and-string

Answer (score 967, accepted):

The same as in JavaScript, using [**Array.prototype.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
console.log(channelArray.indexOf('three') > -1);
```

Or using ECMAScript 2016 [**Array.prototype.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
console.log(channelArray.includes('three'));
```

---

Note that you could also use methods like showed by @Nitzan to find a string. However you wouldn't usually do that for a string array, but rather for an array of objects. There those methods were more sensible. For example

```
const arr = [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'baz'}];
console.log(arr.find(e => e.foo === 'bar')); // {foo: 'bar'} (first match)
console.log(arr.some(e => e.foo === 'bar')); // true
console.log(arr.filter(e => e.foo === 'bar')); // [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}]
```

Reference

[Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I get an `[ts] Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'` error, do I need to update my tsconfig to support this ecma 6 feature?

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to add "es7" into the array for property "lib" in my tsconfig.json file, eg. `"lib": ["es7", "dom"]`

Answer (score 165):

You can use the [some method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
console.log(channelArray.some(x => x === "three")); // true
```

You can use the [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
console.log(channelArray.find(x => x === "three")); // three
```

Or you can use the [indexOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
console.log(channelArray.indexOf("three")); // 2
```

Answer (score 70):

If your code is ES7 based (or upper versions):

```
channelArray.includes('three'); //will return true or false
```

If not, for example you are using IE with no babel transpile:

```
channelArray.indexOf('three') !== -1; //will return true or false
```

the `indexOf` method will return the position the element has into the array, because of that we use `!==` different from -1 if the needle is found at the first position.

Answer (score 38):

Also note that ["in" keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Relational)  does not work on arrays. It works on objects only.

```
propName in myObject
```

Array inclusion test is

```
myArray.includes('three');
```

Comment: That's a pitfall worth mentioning, particularly if you come from Python. Even worse, it somehow works on arrays as well since they are objects, too. I just doesn't work in the way you probably think it should - it checks whether something exists in the array as index instead.

Answer (score 24):

Use **JavaScript Array includes()** Method

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
```

Try it Yourself » [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_includes_array)

**Definition**

The **includes()** method determines whether an array contains a specified element.

This method returns true if the array contains the element, and false if not.

Answer (score 9):

TS has many utility methods for arrays which are available via the prototype of Arrays. There are multiple which can achieve this goal but the two most convenient for this purpose are:

1. `Array.indexOf()` Takes any value as an argument and then returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
2. `Array.includes()` Takes any value as an argument and then determines whether an array includes a this value. The method returning `true` if the value is found, otherwise `false`.

**Example:**

```
const channelArray: string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log(channelArray.indexOf('three'));      // 2
console.log(channelArray.indexOf('three') > -1); // true
console.log(channelArray.indexOf('four') > -1);  // false
console.log(channelArray.includes('three'));     // true
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter` too

```
this.products = array_products.filter((x) => x.Name.includes("ABC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
departments: string[]=[];
if(this.departments.indexOf(this.departmentName.trim()) >-1 ){
            return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I came across that case. If you need to use `Array.include()` but your variable or constant is:

```
const validNumbers: TValidNumber[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

You will likely face the problem that the "includes" method only accepts the "TValidNumber" type as a parameter, and you are likely passing a "string" to it. I couldn't find an answer in the 20 minutes I spent researching this, so after trying, I found that you can tell or assign the type to "validNumbers" to be both an Array of TValidNumber and an Array of "string" in the following way:

```
const validNumbers: TValidNumber[] & string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

From hating TypeScript to loving it with great force in an instant hehehe, just as it has helped me, I hope it helps a lot of people.

Answer (score -1):

Using the **findIndex** method we can obtain the index of the array and thus achieve a comparison using the **startsWith** method

```js
  const array = ["one", "two", "three"];

  const myArray = (arr, v) => {
    return arr.findIndex((item) => item.startsWith(v)) > -1;
  };

  console.log(myArray(array, "five")); // false
  console.log(myArray(array, "two")); // true
  console.log(myArray([], "two")); // false
```