# NgClass: if array contains item

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to trigger a class if the item exist inside the array, but I can't figure it out.

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of someList">

     <button [ngClass]="{'isSelected': selectedArr contains item}"></button>
    ..
```

`selectedArr` is the array that contains some item.

Comment: you can refere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790602/how-do-i-check-whether-an-array-contains-a-string-in-typescript/42790792 this link also

Comment: @AniketAvhad Thanks, really useful information :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`selectedArr.includes(item)` will work. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Note that if `item` is an object, `selectedArr` will have to have the *same* object, not just an object with the same properties. Otherwise you'll have to find a different way to compare the properties of the objects to see if there's a match. Anyway, any valid JavaScript statement can be used as the value for `isSelected`.

```
<button [ngClass]="{'isSelected': selectedArr.includes(item)}"></button>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Had no clue that JavaScript statement would work :)

Comment: "Note that if item is an object, selectedArr will have to have the same object, not just an object with the same properties."

Thanks for pointing this out, was having some trouble comparing until I saw this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `[class.className]` also to do the same.

```
<button [class.isSelected]="selectedArr.indexOf(item) != -1"></button>
```