# Can't access variable that changes its value inside for in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let lines = ["Hi","Bye","Gone"];

let match = false;

for(line in lines){
  if(line === "Bye"){
  match = true;
  }
}

console.log(match);
```

I want to use the changed value of the "match" variable outside the for function. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Btw. `lines.includes("Bye") // true`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to get the element of the array instead of the index.

Please have a look, [why not use `for ... in` for iterating arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Do not forget to declare the variable `line` as well.

```js
let lines = ["Hi","Bye","Gone"];
let match = false;

for (let line of lines) {
    if (line === "Bye") {
        match = true;
    }
}

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

`in` iterates an object's keys and shouldn't be used for arrays. Use `of` instead.

```js
let lines = ["Hi","Bye","Gone"];

let match = false;

for(let line of lines){
  if(line === "Bye"){
  match = true;
  }
}

console.log(match);
```

It often helps to debug your code to see errors you're making. For that, you could have simply added `debugger`, opened your console and see all the variable's values.

```
for(let line of lines){
   debugger;
   if(line === "Bye"){
       match = true;
   }
}
```

---

Also see [How do I check whether an array contains a string in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790602/how-do-i-check-whether-an-array-contains-a-string-in-typescript/42790792#42790792) for more information on how this check is usually done